# Setar botão invisível depois da execução UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Estou com um dúvida em meu UItableView, eu coloquei um botão na Cell de um TableView.

```
cell.btnDownload.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.btnDownload addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDownloadClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

depois para executar criei esse método.

```
    -(void) btnDownloadClick:(UIButton *) sender{

    // realizar donload aqui //

    Faz o donwload aqui

    // depois de fazer o download buscar a tag e setar o botão invisivel //


    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        UIButton *button = [cell viewWithTag:sender.tag];
        if (ValorTag == 0){
          button.hidden = YES;
        }
    }

    // depois de esconder o botão vou setar em um [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  o ID. 

}
```

neste for que eu estou utilizando a minha tableView fica toda branca depois de clicar no botão, não sei onde posso estar errando!!

Quer esconder apenas o botão que foi clicado depois do download.

Para entender melhor é como se fosse o App Store que vc tem um botão para fazer download e depois de finalizar ele muda de imagem ou some.

Valeu galera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usar tags pra encontrar views deve ser evitado, pois deixa o código difícil de entender.

No seu caso em particular, quando viewWithTag: é chamado na célula com a tag do botão, pode retornar qualquer tipo de view, não necessariamente um botão. Especialmente quando o botão clicado for o primeiro (indexPath.row == 0 == valor default da tag de qualquer UIView)

Além disso, não adianta apenas esconder o botão quando o mesmo é clicado, uma vez que as células da tableview podem ser recarregadas, fazendo com que o botão volte ao estado padrão.

Eu sugiro uma solução diferente ao problema:

1. Crie um array para manter os índices dos botões escondidos.
2. Quando for inicializar a célula no método -cellForRowAtIndexPath: considere o array para setar a visibilidade do botão.
3. No callback do botão, marque o índice do botão clicado e recarregue a célula a qual o botão pertence.

Exemplo:

```
@interface ExampleViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *hiddenButtonIndexes;

@end

@implementation ExampleViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.hiddenButtonIndexes = [NSMutableArray new];
    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ....
    BOOL downloadButtonHidden = [self.hiddenButtonIndexes containsObject:@(indexPath.row)];
    [cell.downloadButton setHidden:downloadButtonHidden];
}

- (void)downloadButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.hiddenButtonIndexes addObject:@(sender.tag)];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

@end
```

Comment: Opa Rafael muito obrigado pela ajuda, realmente eu percorrendo e buscando a tag para ser escondida está escondendo tudo, ex, todos os componentes estavam setado com tag = 0. 

Neste seu exemplo foi de grande valia, eu tive apenas um problema em setar no Array que o valor não era salvo, quando eu fechava o App e reabria o valor não estava mais setado, mas eu usei o 
**NSUserDefaults**. e outro problema que poderia ter futuramente é a referencia do IndexPath.row com o ID do banco. Valeu pela ajuda deu tudo certo. grande Abs.